# Error while saving core data NSManagedObjectContext with non-optional values iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

Here is my dat model:

```
Contact.address————(optional = true, delete rule = cascade)—————>>Address

Address.contact————(optional = false, delete rule = nullify)—————>Contact
Address. apartment———————(optional = true, delete rule = cascade)———>Apartment
Address.landmarks————(optional = true, delete rule = cascade)———>>Landmark
```

I am creating address on private queue MOC.

When I write this:

```
contact.address = nil <— I am hoping that doing so will delete address entity from database
moc.save()  <— main thread MOC
```

It give me this error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)" UserInfo=0x7fa3f2dafc20 {NSValidationErrorKey=contact, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject=<PROJ.Address: 0x7fa3f2f9bbf0> (entity: Address; id: 0xd000000000040008 <x-coredata://E756D530-F841-4F78-AC7F-C50BE4DB88BD/XmppContact/p1> ; data: {
    street = Bla Bla Road;
    contact = nil;
    apartment = "0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://E756D530-F841-4F78-AC7F-C50BE4DB88BD/Apartment/p1>";
    landmarks = "<relationship fault: 0x7fa3f2e70f80 'landmarks’>”;
})}
```

What will be the reason?

I think `contact` is nil thats why it is showing the error.
If so, the n how to delete `address` from `contact`?

Comment: The error message mentions the `Apartment` entity. What does that look like? What relationships does it have to your other entities?

Comment: 'Apartment' is an entity which has one to one relationship with 'Address' and nullify as delete rule. It doesn't have any other relationship with any other entities.

Comment: What about the "optional" flag on that relationship?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention it, it's Apartment---(opt=false, del rule=nullify)-->Address